# Moving TFS Server and TFS Version Upgrade

Tags: tfs-2015, tfs-migration

At my company we are currently using TFS 2010 which has installed on-premise and we are developing application on it that it is contiouusly being deployed on Microsoft Azure platform.

Our plan is to upgrade our TFS 2010 to version TFS 2015 and host it on a VM on our Azure subscription since this will ease our continuous deployment speed very much by removing network latency, in addition we will be able to use TFS new features.

Question I have is,
What do we have to do to move all TFS project work items, user stories and source code to successfully finish this move and upgrade process.

Before you give your answers, please take into account that we also want to create a local users on new TFS server and map domain users which they are created on the company's active directory server, on Azure VM and during TFS movement we would like to be able to show moved changesets, workitems... everything have been created in TFS database with the newly created local users on the Azure VM.

Comment: Can you offer me more information on why you would like to create a local user account to map to that domain user?

Comment: When we move our existing TFS database to TFS installed on Azure VM, our developer shall start connecting to the new TFS server.But at this point, developers' domain user and password would not work because Azure VM will not be connecting to Active Directory on the on-premise domain server. This is why we are planning to create local users on Azure VM and during the migration we wanted to map existing TFS user(actually domain user) to new users on Azure VM. With this we would want to see all existing changesets are related with new local users on the VM.

Comment: Simply what we want to do is we want to change the TFS server which is not connected to any domain. then we wanted to migrate user from domain to workgroup users, then we wanted to upgrade the new TFS server to TFS 2015

Comment: instead of creating local user accounts in the Azure VM and mapping on-premise domain accounts to these local accounts, how about you connect on-premise AD to Azure AD? See: http://blogs.technet.com/b/keithmayer/archive/2013/01/20/step-by-step-extending-on-premise-active-directory-to-the-cloud-with-windows-azure-31-days-of-servers-in-the-cloud-part-20-of-31.aspx and http://blogs.technet.com/b/ad/archive/2014/08/04/connecting-ad-and-azure-ad-only-4-clicks-with-azure-ad-connect.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, please have a check on this blog for the details on how to do migration upgrade for TFS: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tfssetup/archive/2013/12/19/migration-upgrade-from-tfs-2012-to-tfs-2013-with-reporting-and-sharepoint.aspx  (This blog is about how to upgrade from TFS2012 to TFS2013, it applies to TFS2010 to TFS2015 as well)

Then after the TFS server is moved/upgraded successfully, create a user on Azure.

Comment: the link you shared explains mainly upgrading TFS version. Not addresses the moving user definitions.